# Cloud Firestore - selecting region to store data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a product which for legal reasons needs to store user data in a specific region.

I'm using Firebase so I created a project selecting the region it needs to be in however looking at firestore where the user data is kept I can't find anything pinpointing the region the data actually is. The thing which makes me worry the most is the Cloud Functions endpoints start with `us-central1` but obviously that could just be that cloud functions don't exist in the specified region.

Given this is an important matter is there a way to confirm the location of data and even force it to be in a specific region?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Update

Cloud Firestore supports the following regional GCP resource locations, in addition to the 2 multi-region (nam5, eur3) locations:
[image: GCP resource locations]
See the documentation for an up-to-date [list of locations](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/locations).

## Original Answer

Cloud Firestore is currently only available in our US multi-region (Iowa, Oklahoma, South Carolina). As we approach GA we plan to roll it out to multiple locations across the globe and you'll be able to select which one at creation time. Not something you can do today though.

Comment: Ah ok no worries! Just to follow up quickly, does this apply to the normal firebase database solution too and if when do you antipate firestore will be available in all regions (specifically Sydney)?

Comment: Firebase Realtime is zonal within the US and there are no plans for global deployments. Yes, Cloud Firestore will come to Sydney as well.

Comment: Can't wait to use Asia region support asap(in my case, our service is based on South Korea so I'm using Tokyo region on Firebase Storage)

Comment: Ahoy Dan.. Would it be possible for you to take a look at this quesion and provide an approximate release date I can't find one??  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294109/firebase-cloud-firestore-unavailable-in-asia-south1-mumbai/49474799#49474799 Thanks mate.

Comment: Sorry, we don't give forward-looking dates publicly.

Comment: Remember, Cloud Functions don't work outside US-1 region

Comment: That's incorrect @Spock (you are thinking of Firebase Realtime Database which is limited to us-central1).

Comment: @DanMcGrath You can't use http-callable Cloud Functions outside us-1. You CAN make cloud functions that do other stuff, cron, react to db changes etc. But no http callable stuff. So no api for your frontend. No server side rendering etc.

Comment: Firebase's layer on top of Cloud Functions that interfaces with Firebase Hosting does indeed have that limitation (It's a Hosting, not Functions limitation). This is unrelated to how Firestore uses Functions for events for this question, which don't have that issue. It's worth noting that regular Cloud Functions without the Firebase layer can still be called via HTTP and deployed to any region: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http