# Firebase Hosting for a client in Denmark by a group of developers in India

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am working on an application for a client in Denmark, using the firebase Hosting, Firestore and Cloud functions from among the features of firebase.
While creating a project on the console i selected the location as Denmark as well, so my doubt here is once i Deploy the app to my client's system where will the server be location, will all the features work as expected.
If not what configurations are required?

Answer (score 0):

[image: hint]
First of all, you need to read this carefully. Even if you selected Denmark, it does not determine the location of your data for Firebase features.

I recommend you to take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472967/6674670) for Firestore region. In the case of Cloud Function region, it is helpful to look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572246/6674670).